# How to set up typeorm .env file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, nestjs, typeorm

I've created a `ormconfig.env` file in the nestjs starter project and put the variables from [this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-ormconfig.md#using-environment-variables) documentation in there and added this line here

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    TaskModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
}`
```

And the console shows this error:

`Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/Library/Application Support/Apple/AssetCache/Data' at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:904:18)`

How should I properly set up typeorm .env file in nestjs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like node is trying to scan your *complete* file system for entity files and of course does not have the permissions to do so.

Make sure that you have a path within your project folder for the `TYPEORM_ENTITIES` variable.

For example, look for all files ending with `.entity.ts` recursively under the project's `src` folder:

```
TYPEORM_ENTITIES = src/**/**.entity.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as in the question. As the other answer didn't solve my problem, I had to look around. I will leave my solution for those who also have similar troubles with Webpack + TypeORM, as I had.

Here is what I needed to do to make it work.

```
import { createConnection, getConnectionManager } from "typeorm";

// For hot reload to work need to require files
import { Job } from "../jobs/job.entity";
import { JobAction } from "../jobs/jobaction.entity";

export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: "DATABASE_CONNECTION",
    keepConnectionAlive: true,
    useFactory: async () => {
      try {
        const conn = await createConnection({
          ...connectionOption,
          // add entitities manually
          entities: [Job, JobAction],
        });
        return conn;
      } catch (err) {
        // If AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError occurs, return already existent connection
        if (err.name === "AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError") {
          const existentConn = getConnectionManager().get("default");
          return existentConn;
        }
        throw err;
      }
    },
  },
];
```